# how to find the count of Uppercase and lowercase letters in TCL

Tags: tcl, uppercase, lowercase

how to find the count of uppercase amd lower case in tcl
with this code im getting only ascii values

```
foreach character {H e l l o T C L} {
    scan $character %c numeric
    puts "ASCII character '$numeric' displays as '$character'."
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looping through a string yourself, you can use `regexp` to give you a count:

```
set str "Hello Tcl"
puts "Uppercase: [regexp -all {[[:upper:]]} $str]"
puts "Lowercase: [regexp -all {[[:lower:]]} $str]"
```

I'm using `[[:upper:]]` and `[[:lower:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]` because the former will correctly capture unicode upper- and lowercase, rather than just the ones in the ASCII set.

Answer (score 2):

You can test each character with `string is upper $character` and `string is lower $character`.  Note that non-alphabetic characters are neither upper or lower case.  For more info check the documentation at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M10